# Why android.os.Handler's method "postDelay" is delayed 1-3 ms every time

Tags: java, android, multithreading, time, runnable

I done simple timer that count the difference between time of clicking of button, and current time. Every second (1000ms).

The main part is :

```
   Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainActivity.this.timerHandler.postDelayed(this,1000);
        long mlSecondToGo;
        mlSecondToGo = System.currentTimeMillis() - MainActivity.this.clickedButtonTime;
        MainActivity.this.timerTextView.setText(Long.toString(mlSecondToGo));
    }
};
```

Whole code : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7830279

I wonder why it the "1000ms" delay of the handler:

```
 MainActivity.this.timerHandler.postDelayed(this,1000);
```

is delayed of 1-3 every time I call it.

I mean the TextView shows:

1001  then 1002 then 3004 and so on.

I made the video of it (using of Android's 4.4 screenrecord command from ADB)

http://youtu.be/TyFyS6k5L5c

Thank you very much for an answer.

Comment: Timing is never accurate, just 3ms is very good and accurate.

Comment: Thread sleeps and delays are not accurate to the millisecond. The operating system that schedules threads has some "wiggle room" here. If you need accurate timing then don't take thread sleep times into account. Measure time yourself by setting a start point of time measurement and and end point (button click).

Comment: Try with logging, not rendering into TextView, which may take time.

Comment: @devisnik rendering to TextView delay isn't the case here. See that this is calculated before putting to the TextView. And the "handler" is scheduled set BEFORE rendering to TextView

Comment: yep, you're right, sorry.